# reactjs OR condition breaks in the second comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs, or-condition

I'm trying to add different Id to a component based on a certain value.

My approach is like below

```
id={activePage === ('dashboard' || 'evc_detail')? 'bg_gradient':'bg_normal'}
```

In this scenario if the `activePage` is equal to `dashboard` the correct id is added but it does not register if `activePage` is equal to `evc_detail`. Is the way i'm using this condition wrong and how can i solve this?

Comment: You want your id to be `bg_gradient` when `activePage === 'evc_detail'` ?

Comment: @AtinSingh yes  exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to multiple comparisons you'll need to state them manually:

```
(activePage === 'dashboard' || activePage === 'evc_detail') ? 'bg_gradient' : 'bg_normal'
```

Another option is create an array of items (or a Set), and use `Array.includes()` (or `Set.has`) to check if an item is in the group:

```
const gradientPages = ['dashboard', 'activePage']

gradientPages.includes(activePage) ? 'bg_gradient' : 'bg_normal'
```

Your original expression `activePage === ('dashboard' || 'evc_detail')? 'bg_gradient':'bg_normal'` doesn't work if the `activePage` is not 'dashbarod' because of the way it's evaluated:

1. `'dashboard' || 'evc_detail'` is evaluated, since 'dashboard' is a truthy expression, the result is always `dashboard`.
2. 'dashboard' is compared with `activePage`. If `activePage` is 'dashboard' the result is `true`, if not it's `false`.

Comment: If used your solution like this. but did not work.....

       id={(activePage === 'dashboard' || 'evc_detail') ? 'bg_gradient':'bg_normal'}

Comment: Both solutions work - the 1st solution is `activePage === 'dashboard' || activePage === 'evc_detail'`. Note 2 `activePage ===`